Picard-Lindelöf with weaker Lipschitz hypotheses.
Consider the Picard-Lindelöf theorem as stated below.
Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed rectangle with $\left(t_0, y_0\right) \in$ int $D$, the interior of $D$. Let $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a function that is continuous in $t$ and Lipschitz continuous in $y$ (with Lipschitz constant independent from $t$ ). Then there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that the initial value problem
$$
y^{\prime}(t)=f(t, y(t)), \quad y\left(t_0\right)=y_0
$$
has a unique solution $y(t)$ on the interval $\left[t_0-\varepsilon, t_0+\varepsilon\right] .$
Is the theorem still true with the weaker hypothesis (instead of the usual local Lipschitz condition) that for every $y \in \operatorname{int} (\operatorname{Projection}_{\mathbb R^n} (D)) $, there exists some $\delta >0$ and $M>0$ such that whenever $|\tilde{y} - y|< \delta$, we get $|f(t,y)-f(t,\tilde {y})| < M |y-  \tilde{y} |$ for all $t \in \operatorname{Projection}_\mathbb R (D)$?
I have encountered this as an exercise, and I am unsure whether the original hypotheses were mistranscribed or whether this is a stronger version of the theorem.
The following post on this site: Pointwise Lipschitz and locally Lipschitz shows that the condition given is genuinely weaker than the standard local Lipschitz condition, so a new proof method would be needed.
